# Want to start mongodb but facing this kind of error'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying start mongo in `cmd`:

```
C:\Users\Vishal Bramhankar>mongo

'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What I missed here?

Comment: You probably haven't added it to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: the above is the answer if your server is >= 6.0

Comment: Another note, in MongoDB version 6.0 the legacy `mongo` shell is not available anymore. Use `mongosh`

Answer (score 0):

After MongoDB version 6.0 and onwards we need to install MongoDB Shell separately.

1. Configure below path in envarinment variables

   `C:\Program Files\mongosh-1.6.1-win32-x64\bin`
2. Close your `cmd` and open the new cmd again and run below command:

   `C:\Users\Vishal Bramhankar>mongosh`
3. Run below one for knowing DBs:

   `test> shows dbs`

---

MongoDB shell installation:

- https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell